# pyinstaller --noconsole и subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.x, subprocess, pyinstaller

Вот код моего приложения:

```
import subprocess
n = subprocess.call("help")
```

Потом я это собираю так:

```
pyinstaller -F --noconsole *.py.
```

Когда выполняю .exe (собранное приложение), то появляется черное окошко и пропадает (все работает), но я указал `--noconsole`, его (черного окна) не должно быть.

Как избавиться от этого?
PS Можно и альтернативу мне предложить, моя задача вызвать команду shell-а и получить ее вывод в переменную и чтобы это работало с --noconsole.

Comment: вы хотите запустить внешнюю консольную программу, не показывая консоль?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Running a process in pythonw with Popen without a console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1813872/4279)

Comment: Моя задача запустить subprocess и чтобы вывод записался в переменную